# Why is the value of the probability function grater than $1$?

Tags: probability-distributions

[image]

Can you explain me, why $P(x)>1$ or why is the value of the function $≈1.2$ ?

$P(x) ≤1$, right?

Comment: A probability *density* doesn't have to be less than $1$, as long as it doesn't stay that way for an interval of length $1$.

Comment: @lan  Is this a density function? what is the highest value this function?

Comment: @Martin R İs this function not a Probability distribution function?

Comment: @Beginner how would we know if it is a density function? It is your question and there are no words to suggest if it is or it isn't. The answers focus around this because it is most likely that that is what you mean.

Comment: @Beginner again, we can't tell you what the highest value is if we don't have an equation for the function. Do you know the equation? It may be an equation involving $\alpha,s,m$, judging by the key on the graph.

Comment: I was studying Internet resources (related Probability). I wanted to ask because, ou I didnt understand this picture. I am sorry this stupid question..

Comment: No don't worry, it isn't a stupid question and is probably common to people who are learning the topic. I suppose if you included that comment (that you were studying some online resources), it might have been better. No harm done though

Answer (score 2):

The figure in the question appears to show graphs of several *probability distribution functions.* 
A probability distribution function is not a probability.

In order to convert a probability distribution function into a probability, you can integrate it. The integral can never be greater than $1,$ but the function you are integrating can be greater than $1$ over a small enough interval.

Comment: Thank you for answer. What is the highest value this function?

Comment: As someone has commented already, since you have not given formulas for the graphs we cannot say for sure what the maximum value is. All we can do is guess.

Comment: I understood. Thank you very much.

Comment: As DavidK says, for a continuous distribution like this you need to integrate to find probability values, i.e. probability corresponds to *area*. In this analogy your question is like asking "If I've got 1 square inch of material, how come I can re-shape it into a shape that is longer than 1 inch?".

Answer (score 0):

What you see is not $p(x)$, it is $pdf(x),$ which stand for probability density function.

With continuous distributions $p(x)=0$ at every $x$, but $p(a<x<b)$ is the area under the graph of $y=pdf(x)$

Answer (score 0):

> $P(x)\le1$, right?

Wrong - what you are thinking of is the fact that for a discrete probability distribution, all probabilities must be at most $1$, since they have to sum to $1$. This is a continuous distribution, so this restriction no longer holds - the sum being equal to $1$ is represented by an integral: $$\int_\Bbb R P(x)\,\mathrm dx=1$$There are no other restrictions on $P$ other than that it is non-negative.